# Phonegap - Trouble with network plugin and iOS build

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have a problem in Phonegap using the network information plugin and building my app with iOS (It works correctly on Android!).
If I try to build my app with iOS and without the network plugin, it works fine! But when I install the plugin, during the build, it gave me "Check dependencies error".
I use Phonegap 3.3.0-0.19.6 version. How can I resolve this??

This is what I do:

1.I have only these plugins installed and my platforms are iOS and Android

```
sudo phonegap plugin list
[phonegap] org.apache.cordova.geolocation
[phonegap] org.apache.cordova.splashscreen
```

2.I install the network information plugin (downloaded from the site because behind proxy)

```
sudo phonegap local plugin add /Users/admin/Downloads/cordova-plugin-network-information
[phonegap] adding the plugin: /Users/admin/Downloads/cordova-plugin-network-information
[phonegap] successfully added the plugin
```

3.Now it's all ok, I proceed building with Android, and it works fine…

```
sudo phonegap build android
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] compiling Android...
[phonegap] successfully compiled Android app
```

4.But when i try to build iOS it gave me Check dependencies error!

```
sudo phonegap build ios
[phonegap] detecting iOS SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] compiling iOS...
[error] An error occurred while building the ios project.** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
Check dependencies
(1 failure)
** BUILD FAILED **
```

Comment: try this $ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PROBLEM SOLVED - Unbelievable but I need to recreate my project and setting the name with the first letter UPPERCASE. Then it all works!